# Переклад слова "sustainble"

Tags: переклад, from-english

Чи є український відповідник до слова *"sustainable"*, яке вжите у реченні: "If we abandon the current large-scale, wasteful agribusiness model, our food will be more sustainable and more delicious as well". Згідно до [Оксфордського словника](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sustainable) "sustainable" може мати значення: "Conserving an ecological balance by avoiding depletion of natural resources" - "Той, що зберігає екологічний баланс, запобігаючи вичерпанню природних ресурсів". Гугл перекладач дає варіант "стійкий", але він зовсім не підходить по контексту.

Чи існує в українській мові якийсь відповідник який можна було б використати для перекладу цього слова? Перше, що мені спало на думку - *"екологічно безпечний"*, однак він не достатньо передає значення слова.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[r2u](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=sustainable&highlight=on):

> **sustainable** [səˈsteɪnəb(ə)l] *adj*
>
> 1. стійки́й, станівки́й, ста́лий; стабільний; збалансо́ваний, гармоні́йний; невиче́рпливий; самопідтри́мний; екораціональний
> 2. стійки́й, доводи́мий, обґрунто́ваний

Гадаю тут може підійти один з варіантів з пункту 1.

Answer (score 3):

Якщо пошукати "what is sustainable food", то більшість джерел [1] [2] [3] пояснюють це як іжа (а також землеробство), яке:

- Задовольняє потреби людства у їжі та волокнах; Satisfy human food and fiber needs.
- Покращує якість навколишнього середовища та базу природних ресурсів, від яких залежить сільське господарство; Enhance environmental quality and the natural resource base upon which the agricultural economy depends.
- Найбільш ефективно використовує невідновлювані ресурси та інтегрує, де це можливо, природні біологічні цикли і процеси; Make the most efficient use of nonrenewable resources and on-farm resources and integrate, where appropriate, natural biological cycles and controls.
- Забезпечує економічну ефективність сільського господарства;  Sustain the economic viability of farm operations.
- Покращує якість життя фермерів та суспільства в цілому; Enhance the quality of life for farmers and society as a whole

З огляду на вищенаведене, терміни [**Екологічне (екологічно-чисте) землеробство (харчування)**](http://library.kr.ua/orhus/zemlya.html) та [**органічне землеробство (харчування)**](http://www.dachnik.org.ua/organichne-zemlerobstvo.html) виглядають досить вдалими.

- [1] [What is sustainable food?](https://www.sustainweb.org/sustainablefood/what_is_sustainable_food/)
- [2] [10 sustainable foods for your shopping basket](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2010/sep/19/10-best-sustainable-foods)
- [3] [What Is Sustainable Food?](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/dr-john-salerno/what-is-sustainable-food_b_428570.html)

Comment: Думаю що "екологічний" і "органічний" це інші концепції. Тут більше про концепцію Sustaiable Development українською: https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA

Answer (score 2):

Взагалі для *sustainable* у [сенсі, зазначеному bytebuster](/a/4250), на мою думку, в загальному випадку часто найкраще підходить ***[екораціональний](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=sustainable&dicts=1)*** ([обговорення](//r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1392)). Це якщо у відриві від конкретного речення, а просто *sustainable <something>* (наприклад, *sustainable food*).

Але в конкретному випадку, коли треба вищий ступінь порівняння (*more sustainable*), я би справді вжив запропонований bytebuster'ом варіант ***екологічний***:

> Якщо <…>, [то] це зробить нашу їжу екологічнішою, і смачнішою також.